# error: failed to launch '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/ problem still not solved

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode10

All of a sudden I have a problem with my iPhone (iPhone X), even if I went to the general > Device Management > Trust process.

I edited the scheme as well (product > edit scheme > run > ask on launch)

Nothing seems to be working.

What surprise the most is that I have been working on this app for more that a month without any problem, and now it just won't work.

**ps1:** iPhone simulator works perfectly

**ps2:** I managed to get it to work without debugging with 'command + i'

[iPhone has denied the launch request.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GVuO.png)

Comment: I get this error sometimes when my phone is locked. I just clean build folder and launch again. Maybe it'll help you

Comment: @KelvinChong you mean with the 'command + shift + k'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a code signing in issue. Make sure you are signing with developer profile and not from distribution profile. Also, after you try to run your project, clean your derived data.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and have just fixed it by going to my developer account https://developer.apple.com/account/#/overview/ANKJAQWN22 and creating a new development certificate.
I then went into  Xcode/preferences/accounts and clicked "download manual profile"s and checked "Manage Certificates" was showing my new certificate.

Then I did a run and the app installed and ran on my iPhone X where as for the last week I couldn't get it to run.

Hope this helps.